# Force standby de-synchronisation for script testing

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, dataguard, standby

Two databases are configured in a production-standby configuration with Oracle Dataguard.

I want to test a script that supposedly detects whether the dataguard observer is in the status SYNCHRONIZED or not. To do so, I am trying to manually break something to force the synchronization to momentarily fail while I test my script and then fix it.

I already tried stopping the observer but doing so will only cancel the third party status reporting ability of the observer itself which won't affect the databases at all.

A theoretical solution would be to break the network link between the two by disabling the network card. The issue is maybe in this case the observer wouldn't be able to connect to the standby and behave unexpectedly.

Please give me a heads up on where to start here !

Answer (score 2):

Just disable sending redo to the standby on the primary (replace with actual dest number):

```
SQL> alter system set log_archive_dest_state_2=defer scope=memory;
```

To re-enable (replace with actual database name):

```
DGMGRL> enable database orcl_sb
```